# Off-diagonal elements of gram matrix reduce nuclear norm

Tags: linear-algebra

This is my first post on Math StackExchange :).

I am considering a gram matrix $M^T M$ for a skinny ($n \times d$ where $n \gg d$) matrix. The eigenvalues of $M^T M$ are the squares of the singular values of my original matrix $M$.

Under the assumption that the columns of $M$ are orthogonal, the gram matrix reduces to a diagonal matrix where the eigenvalues are the diagonal elements, which are in turn $\lVert c_i \rVert_2^2$ or the squares of the $\mathcal{L}_2$ norms of the columns. The singular values are then the $\mathcal{L}_2$ norms of the columns.
$$
\lVert M\rVert_* = \sum_{j=1}^d \sigma_d = \sum_{j=1}^d \lVert c_j \rVert_2
$$

I wish to show that when the columns of $M$ are not orthogonal and the gram matrix has off-diagonal elements, then the nuclear norm (sum of singular values) of my matrix is strictly less than the diagonal case. In other words, assuming that $\lVert c_j \rVert_2$ stays the same for all $j$, if $c_i \cdot c_j \neq 0$ for any $i,j$, then the nuclear norm is reduced.

I am envisioning some approach with Weyl's inequality but have not found success.

Apologies if my question is poorly worded. I would love to clarify.

Comment: What sorts of tools/concepts are you familiar with?  The proof I have in mind uses majorization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
\|M\|_\ast
=\max_{U\in O(n)}\sum_{j=1}^d(UM)_{jj}
\le\max_{U\in O(n)}\sum_{j=1}^d\|(UM)_{\ast j}\|_2
=\max_{U\in O(n)}\sum_{j=1}^d\|Uc_j\|_2
=\sum_{j=1}^d\|c_j\|_2,
$$
where equality holds if and only if $(UM)_{jj}$ is identically equal to $\|(UM)_{\ast j}\|$ for some orthogonal matrix $U$, i.e., if and only if $D=UM$ is a (rectangular) nonnegative diagonal matrix, but that means $M=U^\ast D$ has mutually orthogonal columns.

Comment: How can one see why the first equality is true?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer It is a well-known characterisation of the nuclear norm using matrix trace. It can be proved by using singular value decomposition of $M$. Essentially, if $M$ is a square matrix (pad it with zero columns if it is not) and $M=USV^T$ is a SVD, then for $Q\in O(n)$, $\operatorname{tr}(QM)=\operatorname{tr}(V^TQUS)=\operatorname{tr}(Q_1S)$ where $Q_1=V^TQU$. Clearly $Q_1$ is orthogonal. Hence $q_{ii}\le1$ and $\operatorname{tr}(Q_1S)=\sum_iq_{ii}\sigma_i\le\sum_i\sigma_i$. ...

Comment: ...Since equality holds when $Q_1=I$, we have $\sum_i\sigma_i=\max_{Q_1\in O(n)}\operatorname{tr}(Q_1S)=\max_{Q\in O(n)}\operatorname{tr}(QM)$. The nuclear norm is also known as the *trace norm* because it is the trace of the singular value matrix in the SVD. The characterisation of the norm above make it possible to define the norm using matrix trace but without SVD.

Answer (score 0):

First, for simplicity assume WLOG that the maximal length column of $M$ is the first column, second largest length column is the second column and so forth.  (If this were not true, use permutation matrix $P$ and consider $M':= MP$, recalling that multiplication by an orthogonal matrices doesn't change singular values).  Now define Gram matrix $G:= M^TM$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n\geq 0$.

Lemma:
the eigenvalues of $G$ majorize those of its diagonal , i.e. $G \succeq_s  G \circ I$
where $\succeq_s$ denotes (strong) majorization of eigenvalues and $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product.
Proof:
Let $E_r$ be a diagonal matrix with the first $r$ diagonal values $=1$ and the rest zero.
$\sum_{k=1}^r g_{k,k} =\text{trace}\big(E_r G\big)\leq \sum_{k=1}^r 1 \cdot \lambda_k$
by von-Neumann Trace Inequality and of course when $r=n$ this is met with equality.

Finish:
The standard real square root map $u\mapsto u^\frac{1}{2}$ for $u\geq 0$ is concave (check second derivative at any positive $u$)
$\implies\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma_j = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j^\frac{1}{2}\leq \sum_{j=1}^n g_{j,j}^\frac{1}{2}=\sum_{j=1}^n \big \Vert \mathbf m_j\big\Vert_2$
by Schur concavity

Remark:
the nth elementary symmetric function is also Schur concave when applied to real non-negative numbers and using it instead of the sum over square roots recovers Hadamard's Determinant Inequality